# laTex/minipage/captionof command

Tags: latex

I am using LaTeX to write my project report and am using `minipage` to insert multiple pictures and also am trying to add caption to every picture but whenever I run my code only the pictures appear without the caption. Below is the code I used

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{yearly1}
    \captionof{figure}{example1}
    \label{fig:figure}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{yearly2}
            \captionof{figure}{example2}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{yearly3}
            \captionof{figure}{example3}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{yearly4}
            \captionof{figure}{example4}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{yearly5}
        \captionof{figure}{example5}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
   \centering
   \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{yearly6}
       \captionof{figure}{example6}
\end{minipage}
```

Comment: Tested it ( adding the necessary \usepackage{caption} \usepackage{graphicx} ) and no problem, do you have a minimal "working" example ?

Comment: @shrimpdrake no please. I have already created a template for my report and I have included all the packages above

Comment: You might want to move this question to the [TeX LaTeX Stack Exchange site](http://tex.stackexchange.com/).